# Parameter of POST method is always null

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I'm developing an ASP.Net Core 2 Web Api and I don't know why I'm getting null the parameter of a POST method.

I've tested it with PostMan:

[image]

And I get the `proOrds` parameter is null:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public void Save([FromBody] List<Models.ProductionOrderPresentation> proOrds)
```

This is the JSON I send:

```
[{
    "ProductionOrderId": 0,
    "ProductId": 7,
    "LawId": 0,
    "Name": "rrrr",
    "Created": null,
    "Phase": 0,
    "NumItems": 123,
    "Reduction": 4444
}]
```

And the class is:

```
public class ProductionOrderPresentation
{
    public int ProductionOrderId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public byte LawId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Created { get; set; }
    public byte Phase { get; set; }
    public int NumItems { get; set; }
    public byte Reduction { get; set; }
}
```

What is it wrong?

Comment: What if you try `Models.ProductionOrderPresentation[]` array instead of  `List<Models.ProductionOrderPresentation>` ?

Comment: @KostyaK Thanks, but it is still null. Maybe the parameter is not in the body but I set it in the body in PostMan.

Comment: Your `Reduction` is `byte` and you pass `4444` for its value which is quite more than range of byte.

Comment: I'm guessing here, but try changing Reduction to e.g. 200. Max value of byte is 255, so maybe it is unable to deserialize the json into ProductionOrderPresentation).

Comment: Also having a `void` action is a bit naughty.

Comment: i think there is no problem with your code.

Comment: @Evk You are right, that was the problem. Please answer my question and I will accept it. Maybe it could help. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidG Yes, I know. I've been testing this part, I will return the data saved.

Comment: @VansFannel i thought you said "And I get the proOrds parameter is null:" which means you are not getting any value at all. that wont happen because of what Evk said

Comment: I was looking for an error in my code or JSON format and I hadn't checked all values.

Comment: I guess it happens to most guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Reduction` column is of type `byte` which has range 0-255, but you pass `4444` as a value for that column. So item you post does not really map to your model class and so is ignored by asp.net.